# Store and retrieve a Data structure

Tags: c++

I have a situation where I'm parsing an xml file in c++(using libxml) and with the extracted info I'm creating a data structure on the fly & modifying the D.S according to the further extracted info from the parsed file. Now I need to save the D.S as it is, in secondary memory and I want to retrieve back the D.S from memory later so that I can continue working further without the need of creating the D.S once again. Can someone please help me out on how to do this?

Comment: Sure, just make a copy: `DS * backup_ds = new DS(primary_ds);`.

Comment: If secondary memory is disk, take a look at this: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080514040736AAkgqNw

Comment: When you flush your data structure to a disk, you want to serialize it. Are you sure you want to store binary blob? The problem is, when you update your code to modify the data structure, you can't read back what you saved earlier. So backward compatibility is a problem. Why are you insisting not to create the d.s. once again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using a library like [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) for this.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that 'secondary memory' is a hard drive or something. In that case use fwrite and fread, or in C++ overload <<  and >> if you want. How you do this depends on your data structure, if it has members that are pointers then things get a bit more complicated.

There's not enough info in your question to really help you.

Comment: thank u so much for your response. Ok so I'm extracting a list of all component names, type, address, data, parent, hierarchy etc.. (from xml) and creating data structures so that i'm able to connect and instantiate the components, and also classifying them according to the info from the fields i mentioned above. Now I need to dump all the info into a file(in hard drive) and retrieve them back sometime later so that when i parse another xml file, the code should get back the existing Data structure and modify the same..